# SSL PKCS7 not found

Tags: ssl, spring-boot

I try to use ssl with spring boot, i use tomcat embedded

```
server.ssl.key-store: /home/bobby_usr/gym/www_testnorenda_com.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password: changeit
#server.ssl.key-password = changeit
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS7
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type PKCS7 with path 
file:**/home/bobby_usr/gym/www_testnorenda_com.jks** due to PKCS7 not found

i have theses file in the folder: **/home/bobby_usr/gym/**

```
cert.p7b
www_testnorenda_com.csr
www_testnorenda_com.jks
```

edit

i modified ssl.key-store to **www_testnorenda_com.p7b**

i get

```
Failed to load keystore type PKCS7 with path file:/home/bobby_usr/gym/www_testnorenda_com.p7b due to PKCS7 not found
```

Comment: A JKS file is not of type PKCS7.

Comment: tried to use pkcs7 key... see my edit.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't understand 'PKCS7' to me. AFAIK the only supported keystore types are as listed in [KeyStore types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore).

Comment: CertPath Encodings, PKCS7 seem supported